# Hash Match Probe Residual

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-internals

Experts,

I am trying to learn more about the CONVERT_IMPLCIT and Probe Residual.
Can someone explain to me why the following test script cause  Probe Residual?

My understanding is if both join predicate column are of the same datatype and is defined as "NOT NULL" then it should not cause any Residual

**Reference and Test script**

[Join Performance, Implicit Conversions, and Residuals](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/07/19/join-performance-implicit-conversions-and-residuals.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE #BuildBigInt
(
    col1    BIGINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #ProbeBigInt
(
    col1    BIGINT NOT NULL
);
GO

DECLARE @I INTEGER = 1;

INSERT #BuildBigInt
    (col1) 
VALUES 
    (CONVERT(BIGINT, RAND(1) * 9999999));

 WHILE @I < 5000
BEGIN
    INSERT #BuildBigInt
        (col1)
    VALUES 
      (CONVERT(BIGINT, RAND() * 9999999));
    SET @I += 1;
END;



INSERT #ProbeBigInt
        (col1)
VALUES 
    (CONVERT(BIGINT, RAND(2) * 9999999));


WHILE @I < 5000000
BEGIN
    INSERT #ProbeBigInt
        (col1) 
    VALUES 
        (CONVERT(BIGINT, RAND() * 9999999));

    SET @I += 1;

END;


--test query

SELECT
    COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM #BuildBigInt AS bbi
JOIN #ProbeBigInt AS pbi ON
    pbi.col1 = bbi.col1
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

[image]

Comment: Q is perhaps not an exact duplicate but the answer would be the same. `bigint` columns does not have a 'perfect' hash function.